# why table is not creating by this script?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am creating a test script to create database and insert data.
database is created but no table is creating.

here is code.

```py
import sqlite3

def connect()  :
    conn=sqlite3.connect("fullsta.db" )
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS post(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,title text,content text,date text,author text)")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def insert(title,content,date,author):
    conn=sqlite3.connect("fullsta.db" )
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO post VALUES (NULL,title ,content ,date,author )")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

insert("hello","hello","hello","hello")
```

---

here is the error.

```
PS C:\Users\Anil Kumar\Desktop\project\my site\web_blog> py test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 17, in <module>
    insert("hello","hello","hello","hello")
  File "test.py", line 13, in insert
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO post VALUES (NULL,title ,content ,date,author )")
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: post
```

Comment: Did you call ```connect```

Comment: Call connect () - it will create the table

Comment: Unrelated, but DDL statements don't need `commit`

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not have connect function called.

but you need more clearer code to see what is happening.

maybe this will handle what you want to do

```
import sqlite3


class DB:
    cursor = None
    connection = None

    def __init__(self, db):
        connection = sqlite3.connect(db)
        self.cursor = connection.cursor()
        self.connection = connection

    def migrate(self):
        q = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS post(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,title text,content text,date text,author text)"
        self.cursor.execute(q)

    def exec(self, sql, variables=None):
        if variables:
            return self.cursor.execute(sql, variables).fetchall()

        return self.cursor.execute(sql).fetchall()

    def commit(self):
        self.connection.commit()

    def close(self):
        self.connection.close()

    def force_exit(self):
        self.commit()
        self.close()


def insert(title, content, date, author):
    cur = DB("fullsta.db")
    cur.migrate()
    cur.exec("INSERT INTO post VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ? )", (title, content, date, author))
    cur.force_exit()


insert("hello", "hello", "hello", "hello")
```